# How to fetch data on 3 models ManyToMany relationship with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 tables `academic_years, classroom, courses` and also have a pivot table `academic_year_classroom` in many to many relationship with 3 tables.The pivot table has 3 columns `academic_year_id, courses_id, classroom_id`.

The Academic year is the base model of the relationship. A year has many classrooms and each classroom for that year have many courses.

```
//*********ACADEMICYEAR MODEL *************

public function classrooms()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\Classroom', 'academic_year_classroom);
}


//***********COURS MODEL ********************** //
public function classrooms()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\Classroom', 'academic_year_classroom');
}


//********CLASSROOM MODEL **************
public function academicyears()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\AcademicYear');
}

public function courses()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\Setting\Cours', 'academic_year_classroom', 'classroom_id', 'courses_id');
}
```

I have defined the pivot table has follow:

```
Schema::create('academic_year_classroom', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('academic_year_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('classroom_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('courses_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

I'm able to fetch all Years and their classrooms for each year without any problem. I'm also able to fetch courses for each year separately.

```
return $year = AcademicYear::with('classrooms', 'courses ')->orderBy('year', 'DESC')->get();
```

**BUT WHAT NEED HELP WITH IS THAT**
I want to return all the Academic Years with classrooms for each of the year and the courses that are assigned to each classroom for that year.

I tried this `return $year = AcademicYear::with('classrooms', 'classrooms.courses')->orderBy('year', 'DESC')->get(['id', 'year', 'active_year']);` , it returns each academic year with its classrooms but includes courses of that classroom for all the years that have that classroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out on my way. Maybe this is not the best approach but I least took me somewhere. If someone has a better approach or there is some issues with this approach please feel free to share it here.

> ```
> //1. I was able to return the records for a single year with it classrooms and courses assigned to that classroom as follow:
>
> public function show($id)
> {
>   return $year = AcademicYear::with(['classrooms', 'classrooms.faculty', 'classrooms.courses' => function ($q) use($id) {
>     $q->where('academic_year_id', $id);
>   }])->findOrFail($id);
> }
> ```
>
> I was also able to return the list of all the years with classrooms for each year and the courses that were assigned to each of the classrooms as follow:

```
   public function index()
  {
   // First I retrieve all the Year IDs as an array
    $yearID = AcademicYear::pluck('id')->toArray();

    foreach($yearID as $yr) {
      $year = AcademicYear::with(['classrooms', 'classrooms.courses' => function ($q) use($yr) {
        $q->whereIn('academic_year_id', [$yr]);
      }])->orderBy('year', 'DESC')->get();
    }
      return $year;
  }
```

Again, if you have a better way to approach this, please share with us. And if this answer was helpful please vote it so that it can help others. Thanks.